# variable point to another variable by ref

Tags: javascript, reference

I have a problem that I create a variable with value that not exist yet (other variable)

example:

```
var a=b;
var b=5;
console.log(a)
//I want result to be 5
```

I need it to be without wrapping with function or object (unless I can still call "a" as is and not "a()" )

if 'a' can point to 'b' by ref I will do:

```
var b="temp"
var a=b
b=5
```

so, is there any way that 'b' will point on same location as 'a' ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: do you mean that there is no way of doing this?

Comment: All primitives values like, booleans, strings, numbers, when attributed to another variable, is created a new value by copy. Objects like, arrays, functions and any other type of object are passed by reference.

Comment: correct, this is why I have a problem :)  I thought maybe someone have an "out of box" idea

Comment: No, there's no (generic) solution. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I think in every language, even the functional ones, that have lazy evaluation, you can't simply do that because you're attributing a variable that was even defined yet to "a". And JS will just assume that, "a" will receive undefined. Even if you use a object for "b", you're declaring it after, so before it, it simply doesn't exist in memory.

As Ferdia said, you can deal with **future** values using Promises or Observables, but **first** you need declare the variable you're trying to associate to another :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Promises API could work for you? Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

A trivial example;

```js
var bPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   resolve(5);
});

bPromise.then(function(result) {
   var a = result;
   console.log('a = ' + a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do using a JS **feature**:
As function declarations are hoisted up by the JS interpreter, we can play around creating a "producer" for a "lazy evaluation" (very common in functional languages, but not included natively in JS).

```js
const a = b;
b(5);
console.log(a());

//We just take advantage of the function hoisting and context to do this
function b(val) {
 return val? this.val = val : this.val;
}
```